# 403 Error and PerfMon Metrics Collector issue on JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

I've created a script using Blazemeter, and when I attempt to execute it, I encounter errors during the login step and the steps involving checking user activity. The error code I receive is 403. I've reviewed various aspects, including authentication, certificates, and permissions, but I'm still unable to resolve this issue.

[image]

Additionally, I'm experiencing a problem with the PerfMon metrics collector. While I can see graphs, I'm having difficulty determining which test steps they correspond to on the graph.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases you cannot just replay the recorded script without prior [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters.

It might also be the case your application under test uses external authentication system like [basic access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)). In this case you will need to add property configured [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager), see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-jmeter) article for more details.

With regards to PerfMon plugin - the X axis of the chart displays relative time from the test start, if you detect an anomaly like sudden increase of the number of errors or response time in other charts you can check the same in the PerfMon chart.

Comment: Thanks ! but it is not resolving my issue. Any further suggestions?

Comment: I checked your article at https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-csrf-load-testing. My csrftoken and csrfmiddleware token are different and dynamic. I am not able able resolved 403 forbidden error.  Any suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77380300/jmeter-is-not-accepting-variable-values-for-csrftoken