# JMeter is not accepting variable values for CSRFToken

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, csrf-token

I have created variable named token.
[image]

I have added token in next step ie login step parameter.
[image]

But it is not accepting the token value saved in variable. It is displaying 'token' term and login step look failed. It should take the values of regular expression field shown in first image.
[image]

Comment: Check the response data:

Verify "field to check" option, if its headers or body. you can view extracted values in debug sampler if the values has been extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably JMeter "is not accepting" the variable because your [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) fails to find anything matching the regular expression you've provided in the response headers.

We cannot suggest an appropriate configuration without seeing what does the token look like in the response, my assumption is that:

1. It looks like you're trying to extract a value from an [HTML input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp), in this case you need to switch "Field to check" to `Body`

   [image]
2. [It's not recommended to use regular expressions for extracting data from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), it might be a better idea to consider switching to [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor) instead. And in case if there are multiple inputs (and I believe this is the case) you should provide an unique filter like input's name or ID or whatever, otherwise you will get the first match.

Comment: Thanks ! I am using login form where can I find CSS for that and for which field ? username / password or any other ? any stepwise tutorial or video for css selector for login form ? Is there any changes need to do from Django as application is built in django.